# Creating minimal groups from two lists

Tags: python, algorithm

I have a tuple containing a letter/name and a list of chars. I also have a list of purely chars. The idea is that I want to create new lists containing all the possible combinations of the letter/name from the tuple. Where their respective char list contains all the chars which is in the other char list. However this new list should be minimal, meaning there shouldn't be any redudant letter/names. An example,
I have the following tuples,

```
('C', ['l'])
('D', ['l', 'q'])
('E', ['q', 's'])
('F', ['s'])
('H', ['q', 's'])
```

I should mention that the tuples are in a list aswell. So a list of tuples

The input list is, `['l', 'q', 's']`

In this example I should get the following lists,

```
['C', 'E']
['C', 'H']
['D', 'E']
['D', 'F']
['D', 'H']
```

Because 'C' and 'E' combined gives `['l', 'q', 's']` and so forth. It should not return `['C', 'F', 'H']` Because here 'F' would be redundant.

My first thought was that I would check the result of appending each of them together. However this would not work for a larger example where the return list is larger than two chars.

Comment: Can the tuples be organized inside an iterable, like a list?

Comment: Yes, they are in fact in a list, perhaps I should have mentioned that in my post

Comment: Isn't the grup  ['D', 'E'] redundant because it have two times the letter q -> ['l', 'q', 'q', 's'] ?

Comment: No because group 'D' has ['l', 'q'] and 'E' has ['q', 's']. So to make ['l', 'q', 's'] you would have to have a overlap there. If you were to add group 'C' or 'F', they would in that case be redundant

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
list_tuples = [('C', ['l']), ('D', ['l', 'q']),
               ('E', ['q', 's']), ('F', ['s']), ('H', ['q', 's'])]
input_list = ['l', 'q', 's']
out_list = []
for i in range(len(list_tuples)):
    for one_tuple in list_tuples:
        if list_tuples[i][0] != one_tuple[0]:
            to_compare_list = list_tuples[i][1] + one_tuple[1]
            counter = 0
            for one_letter in input_list:
                if one_letter in to_compare_list:
                    counter += 1
            if counter >= len(input_list):
                out_list.append([list_tuples[i][0], one_tuple[0]])

out_list = out_list[:int(len(out_list) / 2)]
print(out_list)
```

Output:

```
[['C', 'E'], ['C', 'H'], ['D', 'E'], ['D', 'F'], ['D', 'H']]
```

Please note that this code is not efficient, for better results refer to the itertools  library in python that counts with permutation and combination modules.

**EDIT**

A corrected and more general solution:

```
import itertools
import copy

list_tuples = [('A', ['a', 'b', 'd', 'e']), ('B', ['d', 'e', 'i']), ('C', ['i', 'l', 'n']), ('D', ['l', 'n', 'o', 'r']), ('E', [
    'n', 'o', 'r', 's', 't']), ('F', ['a', 'b', 'r', 's', 't']), ('G', ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o']), ('H', ['b', 'e', 's'])]
input_list = ['a', 'b', 'd', 'e', 'i', 'l', 'n', 'o', 'r', 's', 't']
dic_of_list_tuples = dict(list_tuples)
keys = dic_of_list_tuples.keys()
out_list = []
posible_combinations = []
letter_space = []

for i in range(len(keys)):
    posible_combinations += list(itertools.combinations(keys, i + 1))

for one_combinations in posible_combinations:
    for one_letter in one_combinations:
        letter_space += dic_of_list_tuples[one_letter]
    if (all(item in letter_space for item in input_list)):
        out_list.append(list(one_combinations))
    letter_space = []

filter_out_list = copy.deepcopy(out_list)
for one_list in out_list:
    for i in range(len(out_list)):
        if (one_list != out_list[i]) and (all(item in out_list[i] for item in one_list)):
            try:
                filter_out_list.remove(out_list[i])
            except ValueError:
                pass

print(filter_out_list)
```

Output:

```
[['A', 'C', 'E'], ['B', 'D', 'F'], ['A', 'B', 'D', 'E'], ['A', 'C', 'D', 'F'], ['A', 'C', 'F', 'G'], ['A', 'D', 'E', 'G'], ['A', 'D', 'F', 'G'], ['B', 'C', 'E', 'F'], ['B', 'C', 'F', 'G'], ['B', 'C', 'E', 'G', 'H'], ['B', 'D', 'E', 'G', 'H']]
```

Comment: This does in fact work for the given exxample, but in cases where a much larger input list is given and different tuples is given. It does not work, in larger cases you could have result lists with more than two chars e.g. ```[['A', 'B', 'C'], ['D', 'E', 'F'], ...]]```

Comment: Please provide an example with input and expected output for the case you describe @wardz

Comment: Given the following list of tuples,

`[('A', ['a', 'b', 'd', 'e']), ('B', ['d', 'e', 'i']), ('C', ['i', 'l', 'n']), ('D', ['l', 'n', 'o', 'r']), ('E', ['n', 'o', 'r', 's', 't']), ('F', ['a', 'b', 'r', 's', 't']), ('G', ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o']), ('H', ['b', 'e', 's'])]`

And the following input list

`['a', 'b', 'd', 'e', 'i', 'l', 'n', 'o', 'r', 's', 't']`

Sorry for the bad formatting, it is hard to format as a comment
@Mateo Lara

Comment: The above input should produce the following, The resulting list of list should be
`[['A', 'B', 'D', E''], ['A', 'C', 'D', 'F'], ['A', 'C', 'E'], ['A', 'C', 'F', 'G'], ['A', 'D', 'E', 'G'], ['A', 'D', 'F', 'G'], ['B', 'C', 'E', 'F'], ['B', 'C', 'E', 'G', 'H'], ['B', 'C', 'F', 'G'], ['B', 'D', 'E', 'G', 'H'], ['B', 'D', 'F']]`

@Mateo Lara

Comment: Okay, thank you it seems to work perfectly :D One question though. You use the following `all(item in letter_space for item in input_list)`, I am a little confused to how this works. My thought is that it checks for each item in input_list whether the item is in the letter_space, and then it returns a bool. And with the `all` statement you then check if all of the items in input_list is in fact in the letter_space. Is this the correct understanding?

Comment: Yes that is right, the expression 'all(item in letter_space for item in input_list)' checks whether or not ALL the input list letters are present in the letter space (the group of all lower case letters of one combination). @wardz